# Make a histogram by giving the range and height of each bin one by one

Tags: histograms

I got the data of each bin by measurements like `{start, end, height}` and I want something like this picture:

[image]

I have no other data for the `Histogram[]`, just what you can see on the linked picture. So any ideas how to do this in *Mathematica* (version 9)?

(The whole thing is for fitting a distibution curve on it.)

Answer (score 2):

Generate the test data:

```
points = 10;
SeedRandom[123];
xi = Sort[Table[n + RandomReal[{-.2, 1.5}], {n, points + 1}]]
yi = RandomReal[{1, 5}, points]
data = Table[{xi[[i]], xi[[i + 1]], yi[[i]]}, {i, Length[yi]}]
```

This creates the data in the format $\{start,end,height\}$.
Draw the plot:

```
ListPlot[data[[All, {2, 3}]], PlotStyle -> None, 
 Prolog -> {Opacity[0], EdgeForm[Black], 
   Rectangle[{#[[1]], 0}, {#[[2]], #[[3]]}] & /@ data}, 
 AxesOrigin -> {0, 0}]
```

[image: Bar plot]

Comment: `Graphics[{Opacity[0], EdgeForm[Black], 
  Rectangle[{#[[1]], 0}, {#[[2]], #[[3]]}] & /@ data}, Frame -> True]`

Answer (score 2):

First I'll generate some data in `{start,end,height}` format. This data is drawn from a standard normal distribution.

```
data = Partition[Flatten[Transpose[{Thread[{Most[#[[1]]], Rest[#[[1]]]}], #[[2]]}]], 3] &
              [HistogramList[RandomReal[NormalDistribution[], 100], Automatic, "PDF"]]
```

Now you could try using a combination of explicit binning and a height function.

```
hfun[bins_, counts_] := counts
x = Union[Flatten[data[[All, 1 ;; 2]]]];
h = data[[All, -1]];
Histogram[x, {x}, hfun[#, h] &]
```

[image]

Suppose you want to compare it to the underlying distribution.

```
Show[Histogram[x, {x}, hfun[#, h] &], 
 Plot[PDF[NormalDistribution[], t], {t, -3, 3}], PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]

**Edit:**

In this particular case I assume normalized heights because I generated them with `HistogramList` and the setting "PDF".  If this is not the case you may need to normalize them yourself.  This can be accomplished by replacing `h` with `hnorm` in `Histogram` where `hnorm` is given by

```
hnorm = h/Differences[x].h
```

Answer (score 1):

Using the data generated in @shrx's answer:

```
bins = DeleteDuplicates@Flatten@data[[All, ;; 2]];
heights = data[[All, 3]];
Histogram[{0}, {bins}, ( heights &), Axes -> False,  Frame -> True,
 PlotRangePadding -> {{2, Automatic}, Automatic}]
```

[image]

You can also use `RectangleChart` after some processing of `data`:

```
RectangleChart[Prepend[{Subtract[#2, #], #3} & @@@ data, { data[[1, 1]], 0}], 
 BarSpacing -> 0, Frame -> True]
```

[image]

Comment: Yes, this is the same kind of technique that I used in this answer: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/81155/how-to-create-a-bar-chart-from-a-list-of-heights-and-bin-delimiter-positions/151319#151319