# How to create a bar chart from a list of heights *and* bin delimiter positions?

Tags: histograms, charts

Basically, I'm trying to produce the same output that `Histogram[giganticList]` would produce, but starting from the output of `HistogramList[giganticList]` instead of `giganticList`.

The closest I've been able to find is to pass to `BarChart` the bin counts produced by `HistogramList`; i.e. something like

```
bc = HistogramList[giganticList];

BarChart[Last[bc]]
```

This produces a chart whose horizontal axis is improperly scaled, which is not surprising, since I have not given `BarChart` any information that would enable it to do otherwise.  I have not found a way to do so.

---

**Background**

I need the output of both `HistogramList` *and* `Histogram` on a whole bunch of lists.

When `inputList` is small enough, it's no big deal to call both `HistogramList[inputList]` and `Histogram[inputList]`, even if this (according to the documentation) amounts to calling `HistogramList[inputList]` twice.

But I need to do this for several hundred lists, each consisting of about 2 million numbers.  A call to `HistogramList` on any one of these lists costs ~1 minute a pop, so avoiding that duplicate call to `HistogramList` is to me significant enough to be worth the trouble.

The documentation page for `HistogramList` shows that one can pass to `BarChart` the last member of the pair returned by `HistogramList` to *approximate* the output that `Histogram` would produce with the same input, but, as already explained, the resulting chart's horizontal axis is not properly scaled.

The documentation page for `BarChart`, on the other hand, is huge, and is filled with outlandish possibilities, such as how to make a bar chart out of copies of a famous pornographic image (or, rather, of a sufficiently decorous fragment thereof), but I'm having no luck finding in all this clutter a way to do what I'm trying to do.  Too pedestrian, maybe...

---

**Addendum**

For historical reasons I need to stick with the "look" that `Histogram` produces by default, so I adapted [lalmei](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/9831/lalmei)'s answer.

I post my embarrassing, plodding code below, because I'm sure one of you can do it much better.  (More generally, comments and criticism on this code are always welcome.)

```
myHistogram[hl_] := Module[{makexs, makeys, xs, ys},

  (* makexs basically converts { ..., a, b, c, ... } into
     Flatten[{ ..., {a, a, a}, {b, b, b}, {c, c, c}... }]
     ...and then fixes the result's "boundaries" *)
  makexs = Function[Drop[Drop[Flatten[Transpose[{#, #, #}], 1], 1], -1]];

  (* makeys basically converts { ..., a, b, c, d, ... } into
     Flatten[{ ..., {a, 0, b}, {b, 0, c}, {c, 0, d}... }]
     ...and then fixes the result's "boundaries" *)
  makeys =
    Function[
        Flatten[Select[#, (# =!= None &)] & /@ 
                ({First[#], 0, Last[#]} & /@
                 (Transpose[{Prepend[#, None], Append[#, None]}]) & @ #)
               ]
    ];

  xs = makexs[First[hl]];

  ys = makeys[Last[hl]];

  ListPlot[
   Transpose[{xs, ys}],
   Joined -> True, 
   Filling -> {1 -> Axis}, 
   FillingStyle -> RGBColor[0.987148, 0.8073604, 0.4947004],
   PlotRange -> {{First[xs], Last[xs]}, {All, All}},
   PlotRangePadding -> {{Scaled[0.02], Scaled[0.02]},
                        {Scaled[0.02], Scaled[0.05]}},
   AxesOrigin -> {1.02 First[xs] - 0.02 Last[xs], 0},
   PlotStyle -> {Black, Thickness[Small], Antialiasing -> False}
  ]
]
```

Now,

```
SeedRandom[1465];
data = RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[0, 1], 1000];

myHistogram[HistogramList[data]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
   Histogram[data]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

While not a Bar Chart per se, I usually prefer to use the result from `HistrogramList` directly with `ListPlot` and then join the points with  `InterpolationOrder->0`.

```
SeedRandom[1465];
data = RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[0, 1], 1000];
mapoints=Thread[{#[[1]], Append[#[[2]], 0.0]}] &@HistogramList[data];

ListPlot[mapoints, 
  Joined -> True, InterpolationOrder -> 0, Filling -> {1 -> Axis}, 
  Frame -> True, Axes -> False]
```

[image]

#### update

Ok, if you really want the bars, your update gave me an idea.
Essentially add zeros in between the bins and keep the same settings.

```
mazeropoints = 
Thread[{#[[1, 2 ;; -2]], ConstantArray[0.0, Length[#[[1]]] - 2]}] &@
HistogramList[data]
```

Now just join with the original points, and make sure to sort them, or `Joined` doesn't work properly.

```
ListPlot[SortBy[Join[mapoints, mazeropoints], First], 
 Joined -> True, InterpolationOrder -> 0, Filling -> {1 -> Axis}, 
 Frame -> True, Axes -> False]
```

[image]

If you have errors associated with the bins you can also easily add them to the middle of the bins using `MovingAverage`

some fake errors::

```
maerrors = (Sqrt[#]*
  RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[0, 2]]) & /@ (Last@
  HistogramList[data]);

 maMiddlepointserrors = 
 Thread[{Thread[{MovingAverage[#[[1]], 2], #[[2]]}] &@
 HistogramList[data], maerrors}];

 Show[ListPlot[SortBy[Join[mapoints, mazeropoints], First], 
   Joined -> True, InterpolationOrder -> 0, Filling -> {1 -> Axis}, 
   Frame -> True, Axes -> False], 
   Graphics[{Lighter@Lighter@Blue, Thick, 
   Line[{First@# + {0, Last@#}, First@# - {0, Last@#}}] & /@ 
    maMiddlepointserrors}]]
```

[image]

Answer (score 11):

You can already achieve this using `Histogram`. No need to fuss with `ListPlot`.

Use these forms for the [second and third arguments of `Histogram`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Histogram.html#DetailsAndOptions), and ignore the first argument:

> The following bin width specifications $bspec$ can be given:
>
> - $\{\{b_1,b_2,\dots\}\}\qquad$ use the bins $[b_1,b_2),[b_2,b_3),\dots$
> - $\mathit{fb}\qquad\qquad\qquad\,\,$   apply $\mathit{fb}$ to get an explicit bin specification $\{b_1,b_2,\dots\}$
>
> Different forms of histogram can be obtained by giving different bin height 
>   specifications $hspec$ in $\mathsf{Histogram}[data,\, bspec,\, hspec]$. The following forms can be used:
>
> - $\mathit{fh}\qquad\qquad\qquad\,\,$    heights obtained by applying $\mathit{fh}$ to bins and counts

`HistogramList` essentially returns $\{b,\,h\}$, so you can easily create $\mathit{fb}$ and $\mathit{fh}$: they are just functions that always return $b$ and $h$.

This function takes the result of `HistogramList` (or similar data structure) and gives a `Histogram`:

```
HistogramFromHistList[histList_, opts : OptionsPattern[]] :=
  Module[
    {
      fakeData = {0, firstComesANumber, "but anything can go after"}, (*or just use {0}*)
      b, h, fb, fh
    },
    {b, h} = histList;
    fb = b &; (*Last@b also works.*)
    fh = h &;
    Histogram[fakeData, fb, fh, opts]
  ]
```

Usage example:

```
stuf = RandomVariate[BetaDistribution[4, 2], 500];
opts = ImageSize -> 240;

Row[{
  Histogram[stuf, opts],
  HistogramFromHistList[HistogramList[stuf], opts]
}]

(* Passing more arguments to both Histogram and HistogramList still works. *)
Row[{
  Histogram[stuf, {0, 1, 0.05}, "CDF", opts],
  HistogramFromHistList[HistogramList[stuf, {0, 1, 0.05}, "CDF"], opts]
}]
```

> [image]

---

Edit: The same technique can be used to answer these very similar questions:

- [How to create a histogram from a given frequency table](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/70059/how-to-create-a-histogram-from-a-given-frequency-table)
- [Make a histogram by giving the range and height of each bin one by one](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/27591/make-a-histogram-by-giving-the-range-and-height-of-each-bin-one-by-one)
- [Histogram from relative frequency data;](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/103928/histogram-from-relative-frequency-data)
- [Histogram plot for fixed class interval](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/114380/histogram-plot-for-fixed-class-interval)
- [How can we create a histogram distribution from binning data?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/47721/how-can-we-create-a-histogram-distribution-from-binning-data)